# Old Anime Series/OVA

Tags: wild-cardz

There was this anime I watched when I was younger that has been eluding me for years, I hope somebody can find it.

I can't remember the exact plot or story, but the main character was a female with long brown hair. Her outfit was almost like a sailor scout's, but this wasn't sailor moon. The setting was fantasy like, and there was a big emphasis on traditional playing cards and their suits (Like Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, and Spades). There were other female characters who resembled knights/princesses, but again had the whole suits thing going on.

The beginning of this started with the main character sleeping or relaxing by a tree on a hill, I remember that distinctly. Two other scenes come to mind, but that's about it. The next scene I remember from this had two gigantic chess pieces, a black horse and a white horse, speeding out of control towards something. This character was trying to stop one of them from the inside and prevent it from crashing. I remember this pudgy looking villain chasing her, and some fanservice briefly flashes with them accidentally pulling off her pants in an attempt to catch them (can't believe I remember that).

Something happens and towards the end the brown-haired main character was drifting in some purgatory-like place, a void of white, and was presented two different portals to take. One looked menacing, the other didn't. She ended up throwing one of those playing cards I mentioned, a card with the diamonds on it, through one of the portals. Again, there was some symbolism or something with those cards and suits.

This episode or OVA was on a VHS tape, and I got it possibly 10 years ago. I recall it being dubbed in English, too. I hope that narrows down the scope of things, but this is all I remember.
In the credit scene, there were various shots of the other characters, females mostly, and they were ridden with fanservice, with one princess-looking character in shredded cloths, like she's been in a battle.

I hope somebody recognizes this, I'd really love to find it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like [Wild Cardz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Cardz), known in Japan as "Jaja Uma Quartet". It was an old Central Park Media release. The dub stars [Apollo Smile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Smile) as Coco Hearts.

[image: DVD cover of Wild Cardz]

As you remember, it began with a scene of the main character, Jo Diamonds, the brown-haired girl in the center, sleeping on a hill. Most of the OVA involved her chasing two giant chess pieces that were somehow the key to ultimate power. Opposing her was some random sexy woman, and this fellow:

[image: villain]

Here's a picture of them together. I couldn't find it without the caption. Just ignore it. Wild Cardz is really awesome.

[image: villains together]

The other characters on the DVD cover are her allies, Coco Hearts (the blonde with cat ears), Casa Clubs (the girl with purple hair and dark skin), and Sunday Spades (the girl with short teal-hair). None of them really did much.

The scene where Jo is floating in a white void happens towards the end after some kind of big explosion. It happens for basically no reason, like pretty much everything in this show. At some time after that, Sunday Spades finally unleashes her true power, which is to make a big explosion and also blow off all her own clothes and make her hair grow really long. Here's a (NSFW) picture of that:

> [image: fanservice]

If you decide that you want to watch this, you can get the [DVDs from Right Stuf for $8](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Wild-Cardz-DVD-Hyb). Since it's so old, there's no legal streams or digital versions, and since it's so bad, I doubt anyone is going to license rescue it.